# Capture Enter & Spacebar on Windows 8 Metro-style c# Application

Tags: .net, xaml, windows-8, windows-runtime

I am working with C# and XAML, developing a metro style application on Windows 8. I want to capture the enter button on keyup event but it works with all keyboard buttons except enter and spacebar. My code

XAML

```
<Button x:Name="btnName" KeyUp="KeyboardKey_Pressed">
</Button>
```

C# Source

```
 public void KeyboardKey_Pressed(object sender, KeyRoutedEventArgs e)
 {        
     if (e.Key == Windows.System.VirtualKey.Enter)
            ......        
 }
```

I know that if i use TextBox instead of Button, it will work but I want to use a button. How can I do that?

Comment: Isn't using the Button over the TextBox a break from normal UI conventions?

Answer (score 1):

This works:

```
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Input;


namespace YourNamespace
{
    public sealed class NiceButton: Button
    {
        public NiceButton()
            : base()
        {

        }
        protected override void OnKeyUp(KeyRoutedEventArgs e)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Use the NiceButton instead of your Button in the XAML by including the xmlns of your namespace.

Answer (score 0):

According to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh868246.aspx, the:

> ButtonBase (the base class for Button) processes KeyUp so that it can
>   check for the Spacebar or Enter key ... This processing of the event is 
>   accomplished when ButtonBase overrides the virtual method OnKeyUp.

Therefore, to prevent it capturing the Spacebar or Enter keys, create a new button class that derives from Button, override OnKeyUp and do not call the base class implementation.